# jQuery - Multiple audio elements and volume control

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio, flexbox

My problem is the following:

I have four elements. Every element contains an audio file where autoplay and loop is turned on. What I want to achieve is:

1. Toggle between 4 classes (.o-1, .o-2, .o-3, .o-4) just on clicked element, so the opacity will increase on every click and when it reaches `.o-4` it goes back to `.o-1`
2. Volume of the audio should do the same: first value/starting point is 0, after the first click it reaches 0.333, second value is 0.666 and the 3rd is 1. After the last value/4th click the audio should be muted again.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.player {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50vh;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
}

.element {
    padding: 8px;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1);
}

.o-1 {opacity: 0.2;}
.o-2 {opacity: 0.4;}
.o-3 {opacity: 0.6;}
.o-4 {opacity: 0.8;}
```

```html
<div class="player">
    <div class="element">
        <audio autoplay loop>
            <source src="blabla-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <audio autoplay loop>
            <source src="blabla-2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <audio autoplay loop>
            <source src="blabla-3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <audio autoplay loop>
            <source src="blabla-4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljpb8wk3/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your JS? Where should you click to change the opacity, on each one individually? So clicking on block 1 will increase block 1's opacity?

Comment: Yes, on each one individually. Clicking on element 1 will increase element 1's opacity AND volume.

Comment: Have you tried any Javascript? What you want to achieve is fairly simple. volume can be changed VIA (selector).volume = 0.2;

Comment: Did try it with jQuery, but my code was not relevant - unfortunately i'm not really familiar with JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script to change the `opacity` and audio volume at once without using any class.

Instead, it uses some [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attributes to store the actual "level" values of each element.

I didn't touch your HTML or your CSS.
You now have a nice starter script to play with.

```js
// Set a level to each data attribute elements (to start with).
$(".element").each(function(){
  $(this).data("opacityLevel","0.8");
  $(this).data("volumeLevel","1");
});

// On click, check the level.
$(".element").on("click", function(){
  
  var opacityLevel = parseFloat( $(this).data("opacityLevel") );
  console.log("Opacity before: "+opacityLevel);
  
  var volumeLevel = parseFloat( $(this).data("volumeLevel") );
  console.log("Volume before: "+volumeLevel);
  
  // Increment it and ensure to stay between 0.2 and 0.8
  opacityLevel += 0.2;
  if(opacityLevel == 1){
    opacityLevel = 0.2;
  }
  
  if(opacityLevel >= 0.4){
    volumeLevel +=0.3333
  }else{
    volumeLevel = 0
  }
  
  // Store new levels
  $(this).data("opacityLevel",opacityLevel);
  $(this).data("volumeLevel",volumeLevel);
  
  console.log("Opacity after: "+opacityLevel);
  console.log("Volume after: "+volumeLevel);
  
  // Apply the new level to opacity and audio volume.
  $(this).css("opacity",opacityLevel);
  $(this).find("audio")[0].volume = volumeLevel;
  
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.player {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50vh;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
}

.element {
    padding: 8px;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1);
}

.o-1 {opacity: 0.2;}
.o-2 {opacity: 0.4;}
.o-3 {opacity: 0.6;}
.o-4 {opacity: 0.8;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="player">
  <div class="element">
    <audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="blabla-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="blabla-2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="blabla-3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="blabla-4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** (bonus question about changing the volume more smoothly)

So this part would change:

```
if(opacityLevel >= 0.4){
  volumeLevel +=0.3333
}else{
  volumeLevel = 0
}
```

To this:

```
var volumeChangeDelay;
if(opacityLevel >= 0.4){
  volumeLevel +=0.3333
  volumeChangeDelay = 2000;  // Slow increase
}else{
  volumeLevel = 0;
  volumeChangeDelay = 500;   // Faster decrease
}
```

And the "Apply volume" will be:

```
// Apply the new level to opacity and audio volume.
$(this).css("opacity",opacityLevel);
$(this).find("audio").animate({"volume":volumeLevel},volumeChangeDelay);
```

I worked it in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ayygzO?editors=1011).

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer! But will this set the volume to the same level as the opacity? So if the opacity is 0.2 then the volume value is 0.2 too? Because when opacity is 0.2, volume should be 0. When opacity is 0.4, volume should be 0.333 and so on.

Comment: Here it is with two different levels.

Comment: Thank you very much! One little question: after you reach opacity: 0.4 the audio will go back to 0? It should be the following (o=opacity, v=volume): o: 0.2 = v: 0, o: 0.4 = v: 0.333, o: 0.6 = v: 0.666, o: 0.8 = v: 1 and then go back to the first one.

Comment: Did you try the snippet? Console logs are showing the levels. Volume is setted to zero if the opacity is NOT greater or equal 0.4 (in the else part).

Comment: Oh, yes, now i see it! Thank you very much for your help! +1

Comment: Is it possible to make the increasement smooth, make a tween between the two values? I did it on opacity with CSS transition, but how can i do that with volume value?

Comment: That is a good question... You could use an interval to progressively increase the volume from value before to value after and clear the interval once the value after is reached. I will edit about that... As a bonus question ;)

Comment: Et voilà. You can adjust the time for volume to increase. It should be real smooth.

Comment: I tried it with an audio file, but it seems the smooth increasement is not working. Maybe i'm wrong but wouldn't be easier with jQuery's `animate` property? What do you think?

Comment: mmm... I forgot the line where the "temporary volume" is applyed, in the smooth volume loop. That's why. Sure, I should have [tested it using an audio file](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZJJNwP?editors=1011) from the beginning! ;)

Comment: And... Sure! I don't know why I didn't think about using `.animate()`. [Here it is](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ayygzO?editors=1011) with a slow volume up and a faster volume down. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please attempt to do the JS next time before asking questions. This is not the best way to do it but took the least time.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljpb8wk3/2/

All you needed was to change stuff on click. Again, learn this.

```
$(targetDiv).removeClass('o-1').addClass('o-2');
var audioFile = $(targetDiv).find('audio');
audioFile[0].volume=0.4;
```

Working fiddle with the correct selection method for audio tags.
https://jsfiddle.net/Ljpb8wk3/4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the demo, but your solution doesn't change the volume of any audio file. The sound is playing itself, but when i click on the sound's button, it doesn't change the volume, just the opacity. Any suggestion @Gezzasa?

Comment: @22_4 Did the answer above from Louys Patrice Bessette work for you? If not I will have another look.

Comment: Yes, his answer was more than a working solution, but i would love to see a different approach. Thanks in advance @Gezzasa!

Comment: Not a problem. I do know what is wrong with my code though. When selecting tags like 'audio' and 'video' with jQuery it puts them all in an array. Even if there's only one selected. So you'll need to select it as you would select something from an array [0]. I'll be happy to rewrite my code. Just need to get a working audio file to test with. What I did above was a bit of blind coding.

Comment: Thanks @22_4, I fixed the code and it works :). Your autoplay is going to mess with it as all 4 of them start playing at once.

Comment: is it working with the `.animate()` property mentioned above? I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work for me.